# executing multi query in mysql_query() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

suppose i have a query like this :

```
$std_id =   $_POST['std_id'];
$name   =   $_POST['name'];
$family =   $_POST['family'];

$sql    =   "insert into student set
 std_id =   $std_id,
 name   =   '$name',
 family =   '$family'"; 
$query  =   mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

i read in a php security book that if user enter a value for family field like :

```
ahmad';drop database test#
```

can delete database test;

but we know that the mysql_query() function only allow to execute one query .
i want to know how can this input to be unsafe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @ManseUK The question seems to be *not* about how to prevent SQL-injection, but how come that the `mysql_query()` function executes two statements in this scenario.

Comment: @Quasdunk SQL security is not always about running multiple statements - anything could be added to the end of that query that affects the insert

Comment: well gee I hope you add more "security" to your code before it goes live...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many delusions in your question.
Let's sort them out.

1. mysql_query() **doesn't** support multiple queries execution.
   (so, it is useless to delete anything)
2. dropping tables in the separate query is **not** the only way of the SQL injection.
   (so, it is useless to delete anything again)
3. To protect your query you have to follow some well-known techniques, not some handmade inventions of doubtful efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Just worrying about multiple queries is not enough to protect SQL Security ... There are so many questions / answers on SO for you to read about this subject ..

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)
- [GET parameters vulnerable to SQL Injection - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716529/get-parameters-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-php)
- [php sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678245/php-sql-injection)

Also good resources on php.net

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple queries separated by a semicolon is not the only way to exploit your queries, it is just a very simple example. It will work, when you are using [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).

Comment: I think that it is because the question was quite contrary - how to NOT to execute multiple queries

Comment: The question was "i want to know how can this input to be unsafe" which was answered.